# Get string from URL without slash

Tags: php

I have a URL like `http://localhost/m/2016/05/05/sebut-gubernur`.

If link is clicked, I want get `sebut-gubernur`.

Comment: using `$_SERVER['REUEST_URl']` you can get the string and explode the link and get the last index value.

Comment: explode() the link and it will give you an array and then implode() to make the string again..

Comment: try this: `$part = explode("/", urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));`

Comment: You want to get it with javascript (before page reloads) or with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$_SERVER` variable helps your. and also explode function.

```
$part = explode("/", urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));

echo $part[(count($part) - 1)]; //sebut-gubernur
```

> Note: You also need `.htaccess` code for this kind of url.

OR

If you have the link as a string and want to get `sebut-gubernur` then try:

```
$link = 'http://localhost/m/2016/05/05/sebut-gubernur';
$part = explode("/", urldecode($link));

echo $part[(count($part) - 1)]; //sebut-gubernur
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
```